# Do you know about any book which discusses solitons in Benjamin-Ono Equation?

Tags: resource-recommendations, non-linear-systems, integrable-systems, solitons

Benjamin-Ono equation is an integrable equation with soliton solutions. There are many books on solitons. The ones I know about mainly discuss solitons in Korteweg de-Vries and related equations. Do you know about any book which discusses solitons in Benjamin-Ono equation?

Comment: Ablowitz has two books on inverse scattering, (1.) Ablowitz & Clarkson: Solitons, nonlinear evolution equations and inverse scattering and (2.) Ablowitz & Segur: Solitons and the Inverse Scattering Transform both discuss the B-O but probably the #2 has even more painful details...

Comment: Got it! I knew about the second book but somehow missed that it discusses B-O equation.